Resources for learning about the theory behind interpolation
I would love to learn more about interpolation. However, most resources I have found just show the methods and do not give any theoretical justification.
I am looking for a textbook/lecture notes on this topic which also proves some theorems giving bounds on how good the approximation will be. I would be especially happy to read something written for a more advanced student and it would be preferable if the material has explicitly written theorems and properly written proofs.
Are there any such materials? I am struggling to find any good resources...
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.


Numerical Mathematics by A. Quarteroni, R. Saaco, and F. Saleri, 2007.  |
Approximation Theory and Approximation Practice by Lloyd N. Trefethen, 2019  |
Concise Numerical Mathematics by R. Plato, 2003

